# FactoryGirl Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have the following associations and am trying to implement some factories that allow me to test fully with a `has_many` and `has_many_through` association

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  has_many :image_categories
  has_many :images, through: :image_categories
end

class ImageCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Holds image_id and category_id to allow multiple categories to be saved per image, as opposed to storing an array of objects in one DB column
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :category
end
```

So with ImageCategory I am under the impression that when i save an `Image` object the `image_id` and `category_id` will save in the `ImageCategory` Table? I have yet to see this mind in my application

So when creating a factory this is what i have so far

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    title 'Test Title'
    description 'Test Description'
    photo File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/louvre_under_2mb.jpg")

  factory :image_with_category, parent: :image do
    categories { build_list :category, 1 }
  end

  factory :image_no_title do
    title nil
  end

 factory :image_no_description do
   description nil
 end

 factory :image_no_category, parent: :image do 
   categories { build_list :category, 0 }
 end
end
 end
```

I don't understand what the integer value is after the `category` in build_list? is it the number of instances ?

This test will pass

```
it 'is valid with an associated Category' do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:image_with_category)).to be_valid
end
```

yet this one will fail

```
it 'is invalid with no category' do
  @image = FactoryGirl.build(:image_no_category)
  @image.save
  expect(@image.errors[:category]).to eq(["Don't forget to add a Category"])
end

expected: ["Don't forget to add a Category"]
got: []
```

What have i done wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a validation do add such an error?

Comment: in my category model i have `validates :name, presence: { message: "Don't forget to add a Category" }`, should i add a validation in the `Image` model to look for an integer on the categories ?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the `build_list` is the FactoryGirl helper for building instances. And in your second test you don't have any errors because you don't have any validation at all.

Comment: thanks, so at least I know the FactoryGirl object is building correctly, as for validating the category, within the Image model how would i check ? `validates :categories, presence: true` but i get ` Categories can't be blank
` returned on my first test

Comment: I think you should begin from this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: thanks, `validated_associated` was part of the answer, now i just need to pass categories as nil now for the final part

Comment: In your place I would use validates_presence_of instead of validated_associated

Comment: but that's when i get `but got errors: Categories can't be blank` with my first test